# Problem starting with chronometer

Tags: android, chronometer

My chronometer is always starting from 0:10 or like some other times... it s not starting from 0:01 itself..any one can help me

Thank you,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

i got an answer

```
  final Chronometer chrono = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

  chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
  chrono.start();
```

once it will help to others thank you,,

Comment: Saved the day - but why does android have to be so complicated for no reason!

Answer (score 0):

you can start chronometer any value you want using setBase method of chronometer.you can also calculate Elapsed Time during start and stop of chronometer